# Will TCP connection lose packets?

Tags: sockets, tcp

Say Server S have a successful TCP connection with Client C.

C is keep sending 256-byte-long packets to S.

Is it possible that one of packets only receive part of it, but the connection does not break (Can continue receive new packets correctly)?

I thought TCP protocol itself will guarantee not lose any bytes while connecting. But seems not?

P.S. I'm using Python's [socketserver](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html) library.

Comment: The last time I heard someone complain about TCP losing packets, it turned out they did not check the return values of send/recv or write/read or close.

Comment: @ZanLynx That's what also exactly happened to me :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TCP protocol does guarantee delivery. Thus (assuming there are no bugs in your code and in the TCP stack), the scenario you describe is impossible.

Do bear in mind that TCP is stream- rather than packet-oriented. This means that you may need to call `recv()` multiple times to read the entire 256-byte packet.

Comment: I thought that a packet could be lost, could be checked by the session flag in the tcp header or equal, and when it is it will be retransmitted over the wire?

Comment: @KristerAndersson You will either get an error when receiving or the next bytes sent. You won't get anything else. Specifically, you won't get bytes out of sequence, or with gaps.

Answer (score 1):

As @NPE said, TCP is a stream oriented protocol, that means that there is no guarantee on how much data bytes are sent in each TCP packet nor how many bytes are available for reading in the receiving socket. What TCP ensures is that the receiving socket will be provided with the data bytes in the same order that they were sent.

Consider a communication through a TCP connection socket between two hosts `A` and `B`.

When the application in `A` requests to send 256 bytes, for example, the `A`'s TCP stack can send them in one, or several individual packets, or even wait before sending them. So, `B` may receive one or several packets with all or part of the bytes requested to be sent by `A`, and so, when the application in `B` is notified of the availability of received bytes, it's not sure that it could read at once the 256 bytes.

The only guaranteed thing is that the bytes `B` reads are in the same order that `A` sent them.