# TCP packets loss ratio

Tags: python, tcp, scapy, packet, packet-loss

I'm trying to calculate and qualify video QoE [Quality of Experience] from youtube. I have a student project and I should calculate MDI [Media Delivery Index], I calculated DF [Delay Factor] by sniffing packets and according to RFC 4445. Now I need to calculate MLR too, but there is a problem I used a sequence number of TCP packets to get the number of excepted packets sent from youtube and number of received packets that I stored them in a list.

> MLR = (excepted_packets - receivred_packets)/ interval time

So the problem is the sequence numbers do not increase one by one and there is a big gap between them packets then MRL became a big number.

I will pleasure if you help to know "How to calculate TCP packet loss rate?"

and layers of the packet is :

> Eth => IP => TCP => RAW

Comment: Packets. The word is packets. Not packages. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: @EJP sorry it was a mistake. I mean PACKETS

Comment: TCP just has segment rather than packets concept.
TCP protocol itself will guarantee not lose any bytes while connecting. please refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841896/will-tcp-connection-lose-packets